# Set a cron job to delete a specific database table table every midnight

Tags: database, mysql

my name is frank, i have been trying to create a cronjob that will be deleting a database table every 12 midnight but i found no help, below is the database table. please any help?

```
DELETE FROM X51g_myCRED_log WHERE ref = 'link_click'
```

Answer (score 0):

The sql command for dropping a table would be something like:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS X51g_myCRED_log
```

That would drop (delete) the table 'X51g_myCRED_log'.

You can accomplish this with WP CLI:

```
wp db query "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS X51g_myCRED_log".
```

Be careful, I havent tested this, but this should point you in the right direction

Comment: Yea thank you very much, but please I want to make it to be deleting the logs every 12 midnight